# How to install rpm-python binding to python3 site-packages

Tags: python-3.x, rpm, centos6

I have python2.7 and python3.8 installed on Centos 6.10.

Current Rpm version is 4.8.0. Python2.7 is managed to import the rpm module but not Python3.8.

These are the files in python2.7/site-packages/rpm directory

```
__init__.py
__init__.pyo
__init__.pyc
_rpmmodule.so
_rpmbmodule.so
transaction.py 
transaction.pyc
transaction.pyo
```

How to add the rpm-python to Python3/site-packages so that it can be imported.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely wrong. Even if you copy it to python3.8 directory, it will not work. Because of missing .so libraries or in incorrect version. Or because of incompatibilities between python2 and python3.

If you need python3 then use CentOS 8. CentOS 6 is EOLed anyway.

Comment: For some reason I have to stick to CentOS 6 (32bit). Is it possible to install latest RPM to support python3 and python2?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But you will have to install newer glibc. Which will mean you will have to install newer NetworkManager.  And libselinux. And lua. And... you end up with **EVERYTHING** reinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

The Python source code for RPM is inside the RPM package.
You can download it from http://rpm.org/download.html

And when running the configure script, make sure to specify the `--enable-python` option.
Python 3 should be detected, and the bindings + the libraries created and then installed.

I just tested this with Python 3.9.6 and RPM 4.7.0